# How do I use tar to transfer through ssh on a non standard port?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, tar

I am trying to transfer all files from within a directory through tar as follows:

```
tar cz * | ssh -p 57310 root@example.com tar xzv -C /home/site/www
```

and the error that is returned is

```
stdin: is not a tty
tar: includes: file changed as we read it
tar: /home/site/www: Cannot chdir: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I am connecting to example.com using ssh key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
 tar cz * | ssh -p XXX account@host "cat | tar xvz -C /home/site/www"
```

Comment: This, by far, in my experience, is the fastest way to move files between computers that are connected over the internet.